Looking for movie about time traveling
I'm looking for a movie seen maybe 5 to 15 years ago, possible older.
The movies is about time traveling and at one or multiple points in the movie they change the timeline and see the changes 'ripple' through.
I distinctly remember one scene where they change something in the timeline which causes maybe a sort of apocalyptic event and the city they are in get overgrown by plants. You actually see the changes rippling through gradually, think this:


Seeing that this might happen in multiple movies, do you remeber anything else? The specific plot, the tone (action? comedy? suspense?), the characters or actors?

How about this 2002 loose adaptation of H G Wells' book "The Time Machine"?
Trailer:



Traveling scene that kinda matches what you're describing



